# How to load combined data in R

Tags: r

I get 60 Excel files that look like this (the original file has 135 rows):

```
structure(list(Ce = c(NA, NA, NA, "AC12-PRD-C1", "Camarda", "45431", 
"171,0 cm", "754 mmHg", "20W-25W", "RÈsumÈ", NA, "Moyennag", 
"Time", "Load", "V'O2", "VO2/kg", "dO2/dW", "V'CO2", "MET", "RER", 
"V'E", "BF", "VTex", "PETO2", "PETCO2", "EqCO2", "EqO2", "HR", 
"HRR %", "SpO2", "O2/HR", "Ce", NA, NA, NA, "AC12-PRD", NA, "t-ph", 
"min", NA, "9.7222222222222224E-3", "1.9444444444444445E-2", 
"2.9166666666666664E-2", "3.888888888888889E-2", "4.9999999999999996E-2", 
"6.1111111111111116E-2", "7.2222222222222229E-2", "8.2638888888888887E-2", 
"9.1666666666666674E-2", "0.10208333333333335", "0.1111111111111111", 
"0.12430555555555556", "9.7222222222222224E-3", "2.013888888888889E-2", 
"3.0555555555555555E-2", "4.0972222222222222E-2", "5.0694444444444452E-2", 
"6.1805555555555558E-2", "7.1527777777777787E-2", "8.3333333333333329E-2", 
"9.2361111111111116E-2", "0.10347222222222223", "0.11319444444444444", 
"0.12361111111111112", NA, "t-ph", "min", NA, "9.7222222222222224E-3", 
"2.013888888888889E-2", "3.0555555555555555E-2", "4.0972222222222222E-2", 
"5.0694444444444452E-2", "6.1805555555555558E-2", "7.1527777777777787E-2", 
"8.3333333333333329E-2", "9.2361111111111116E-2", "0.10347222222222223", 
"0.11319444444444444", "0.12361111111111112", NA, "t-ph", "min", 
NA, "1.0416666666666666E-2"), `ntre …` = c("5055", NA, NA, "linear", 
NA, "54", NA, NA, "+ 15W", NA, NA, "e temp", NA, NA, NA, "ml", 
"ml/m", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
"ntre …", "5055", NA, NA, "-C", NA, "Load", "W", NA, "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "20", "20", 
"20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", NA, 
"Load", "W", NA, "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", "20", 
"20", "20", "20", "20", NA, "Load", "W", NA, "25"), `PIC, Insti` = c("rue St Zot", 
"tÈl.", "fax.", NA, NA, "masc", "84", "01/0", NA, NA, NA, "orel 15 Se", 
"min", "W", "ml/min", "/min/kg", "in/Watt", "ml/min", NA, NA, 
"L/min", "1/min", "L", "mmHg", "mmHg", NA, NA, "1/min", "%", 
"%", "ml", "PIC, Insti", "rue St Zot", "tÈl.", "fax.", NA, NA, 
"HR", "1/min", NA, "73", "71", "74", "72", "81", "77", "78", 
"77", "78", "76", "76", "80", "86", "82", "85", "84", "85", "86", 
"86", "86", "90", "89", "90", "91", NA, "HR", "1/min", NA, "86", 
"82", "85", "84", "85", "86", "86", "86", "90", "89", "90", "91", 
NA, "HR", "1/min", NA, "92"), `tut de` = c("ique E", "-514", 
"-514", NA, "Ant", "ulin", "kg", "9/2016", NA, "ThÈo", NA, "con", 
NA, "163", "2041", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "71", "29", NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "170", NA, NA, "12.1", "tut de", "ique E", "-514", "-514", 
NA, "Rep", "BF", "1/min", NA, "24", "22", "22", "22", "22", "19", 
"19", "19", "19", "20", "19", "18", "25", "24", "24", "24", "22", 
"23", "21", "21", "22", "19", "23", "24", "RÈfÈr", "BF", "1/min", 
NA, "25", "24", "24", "24", "22", "23", "21", "21", "22", "19", 
"23", "24", "Exer", "BF", "1/min", NA, "23"), Cardiolo = c("st, Montr", 
"3741480", "3742416", NA, "oine", NA, NA, NA, NA, "Repos", NA, 
NA, "0.12430555555555556", "0", "380", "4.5", "0.00", "347", 
"1.3", "0.91", "14", "18", "0.777", "111.75", "34.10", "37.4", 
"34.1", "80", "53", "-4", "4.8", "Cardiolo", "st, Montr", "3741480", 
"3742416", NA, "os", "V'E", "L/min", NA, "12", "13", "14", "12", 
"9", "12", "12", "12", "13", "14", "13", "14", "15", "17", "18", 
"18", "18", "18", "20", "19", "22", "22", "21", "22", "ence", 
"V'E", "L/min", NA, "15", "17", "18", "18", "18", "18", "20", 
"19", "22", "22", "21", "22", "cice", "V'E", "L/min", NA, "23"
), `gie de M` = c("Èal, HT1", NA, NA, NA, NA, "62 AnnÈ", "Dr Math", 
"0.62850694444444444", NA, "AT", "Manuel", NA, "0.33333333333333331", 
"40", "823", "9.8", "11.08", "704", "2.8", "0.86", "23", "23", 
"0.996", "101.82", "40.90", "30.1", "25.7", "94", "45", "-4", 
"8.8", "gie de M", "Èal, HT1", NA, NA, NA, NA, "V'O2", "ml/min", 
NA, "365", "389", "417", "310", "281", "364", "354", "382", "401", 
"405", "349", "380", "461", "516", "566", "594", "626", "641", 
"720", "664", "789", "724", "746", "762", NA, "V'O2", "ml/min", 
NA, "461", "516", "566", "594", "626", "641", "720", "664", "789", 
"724", "746", "762", NA, "V'O2", "ml/min", NA, "777"), ontrÈal = c("1N6", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, "es", "ieu Gayda", "8", NA, "MaxVO2", NA, NA, 
"0.54166666666666663", "115", "1703", "20.3", "11.50", "2034", 
"5.8", "1.19", "62", "27", "2.316", "112.88", "40.62", "29.5", 
"35.2", "139", "18", "-4", "12.2", "ontrÈal", "1N6", NA, NA, 
NA, NA, "V'CO2  d", "ml/min", "m", "283", "309", "344", "264", 
"210", "296", "283", "304", "325", "339", "299", "347", "370", 
"427", "464", "491", "506", "512", "591", "559", "655", "658", 
"640", "657", NA, "V'CO2  d", "ml/min", "m", "370", "427", "464", 
"491", "506", "512", "591", "559", "655", "658", "640", "657", 
NA, "V'CO2  d", "ml/min", "m", "677"), ...8 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, "VÈlo", NA, "MaxVO2", "%thÈo.", NA, NA, "71", "83", 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "87", "93", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "82", NA, 
NA, "101", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "O2/dW", "ml/", "in/Watt", 
"0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", 
"0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "0.00", "4.03", "6.76", "9.30", "10.70", 
"12.27", "13.04", "16.97", "14.20", "20.42", "17.16", "18.29", 
"19.06", NA, "O2/dW", "ml/", "in/Watt", "4.03", "6.76", "9.30", 
"10.70", "12.27", "13.04", "16.97", "14.20", "20.42", "17.16", 
"18.29", "19.06", NA, "O2/dW", "ml/", "in/Watt", "19.81"), ...9 = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "RER", NA, NA, "0.78", "0.80", "0.83", "0.85", 
"0.75", "0.82", "0.80", "0.79", "0.81", "0.84", "0.86", "0.91", 
"0.80", "0.83", "0.82", "0.83", "0.81", "0.80", "0.82", "0.84", 
"0.83", "0.91", "0.86", "0.86", NA, "RER", NA, NA, "0.80", "0.83", 
"0.82", "0.83", "0.81", "0.80", "0.82", "0.84", "0.83", "0.91", 
"0.86", "0.86", NA, "RER", NA, NA, "0.87"), ...10 = c(NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "Max", "Watts", NA, "0.55208333333333337", 
"130", "1583", "18.9", "9.25", "1952", "5.4", "1.23", "64", "30", 
"2.114", "14.84", "39.35", "31.5", "38.8", "142", "16", "-4", 
"11.2", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "EqO2", NA, NA, "27.6", "29.3", 
"30.8", "33.9", "25.3", "30.3", "28.9", "29.1", "29.2", "30.5", 
"32.9", "34.1", "29.4", "28.8", "28.0", "27.0", "26.3", "25.9", 
"25.7", "26.3", "25.3", "28.6", "26.4", "27.3", NA, "EqO2", NA, 
NA, "29.4", "28.8", "28.0", "27.0", "26.3", "25.9", "25.7", "26.3", 
"25.3", "28.6", "26.4", "27.3", NA, "EqO2", NA, NA, "27.4"), 
    ...11 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "EqCO2", NA, NA, 
    "35.7", "36.8", "37.3", "39.9", "33.8", "37.2", "36.2", "36.6", 
    "36.0", "36.5", "38.4", "37.4", "36.6", "34.9", "34.2", "32.7", 
    "32.5", "32.5", "31.4", "31.2", "30.5", "31.4", "30.8", "31.7", 
    NA, "EqCO2", NA, NA, "36.6", "34.9", "34.2", "32.7", "32.5", 
    "32.5", "31.4", "31.2", "30.5", "31.4", "30.8", "31.7", NA, 
    "EqCO2", NA, NA, "31.5"), ...12 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "PETCO2", "mmHg", NA, "35.68", "32.78", "35.26", "33.61", 
    "36.27", "35.53", "35.87", "36.38", "36.51", "36.36", "35.92", 
    "34.10", "36.80", "36.34", "37.09", "32.65", "38.35", "38.99", 
    "39.26", "39.91", "39.95", "39.22", "40.18", "39.63", NA, 
    "PETCO2", "mmHg", NA, "36.80", "36.34", "37.09", "32.65", 
    "38.35", "38.99", "39.26", "39.91", "39.95", "39.22", "40.18", 
    "39.63", NA, "PETCO2", "mmHg", NA, "39.66"), ...13 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "VES (ml)", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "86"), ...14 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "VESi (ml/m²)", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "42.6"), ...15 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "FC (bpm)", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "90"), ...16 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "QC (l/min)", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "7.8"), ...17 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "IC (l/min/m²)", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "3.9"), ...18 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "PAS (mmHg)", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "120"), ...19 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "PAD (mmHg)", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "74"), ...20 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "PAM (mmHg)", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "94"), ...21 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "ICT", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "153"), ...22 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "TEV (ms)", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "415.6"), ...23 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "RPD (%)", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "49.3"), ...24 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "WCI (kg.m/m²)", NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "4.7"), ...25 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "RVSi (dyn.s/cm5.m²)", NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "1819"
    ), ...26 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "RVS (dyn.s/cm5)", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "901"), ...27 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "VTD est (ml)", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "137.5"), ...28 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "FE est (%)", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "62.7"), ...29 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "O2Hb", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "3.8E-3"), ...30 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "HHb", 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, "-0.29199999999999998"), ...31 = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, "tHb", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "-0.28820000000000001"), ...32 = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "HbDiff", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, "0.29580000000000001"
    )), row.names = c(NA, -85L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

I want to get rid of rows and columns to make my files all looking like this:

```
structure(list(time = c("00:15", "00:30", "00:46", "01:00", "01:15", 
"01:31", "01:46", "01:59", "02:14", "02:30", "02:44", "02:59", 
"03:16", "03:29", "03:46", "03:57", "04:14", "04:31", "04:44", 
"05:00", "05:16", "05:30", "05:46", "06:01", "06:15", "06:31", 
"06:44", "07:00", "07:16", "00:01"), power = c(25, 25, 25, 25, 
40, 40, 40, 40, 55, 55, 55, 55, 70, 70, 70, 70, 85, 85, 85, 85, 
100, 100, 100, 100, 115, 115, 115, 115, 130, 130), hr = c(92, 
90, 86, 87, 93, 91, 95, 94, 98, 100, 101, 100, 108, 108, 110, 
113, 115, 118, 120, 122, 122, 126, 130, 130, 131, 136, 137, 139, 
142, 144), fr = c(23, 22, 21, 25, 25, 22, 22, 23, 24, 23, 23, 
21, 22, 24, 24, 22, 23, 23, 22, 23, 25, 26, 27, 26, 30, 27, 27, 
28, 30, 31), VE = c(23, 23, 25, 20, 23, 25, 24, 23, 25, 26, 28, 
28, 32, 33, 32, 33, 37, 42, 38, 41, 47, 48, 48, 50, 52, 56, 55, 
60, 65, 64), absVO2 = c(0.777, 0.744, 0.761, 0.674, 0.808, 0.868, 
0.787, 0.816, 0.921, 0.935, 0.989, 0.96, 1.05, 0.994, 1.121, 
1.136, 1.227, 1.193, 1.164, 1.212, 1.333, 1.289, 1.358, 1.403, 
1.463, 1.494, 1.441, 1.593, 1.585, 1.515), VCO2 = c(0.677, 0.68, 
0.728, 0.583, 0.689, 0.766, 0.714, 0.691, 0.784, 0.825, 0.9, 
0.907, 1.008, 0.982, 1.066, 1.132, 1.204, 1.269, 1.241, 1.291, 
1.463, 1.488, 1.527, 1.596, 1.633, 1.756, 1.74, 1.912, 1.972, 
1.93), PETCO2 = c(39.66, 39.08, 38.76, 39.67, 39, 39.4, 38.71, 
41.37, 41.02, 41.19, 41.54, 41.89, 41.12, 41.16, 42.98, 42.8, 
42.53, 40.75, 42.64, 41.45, 40.82, 40.23, 41.46, 41.87, 41.37, 
40.54, 40.36, 40.64, 39.3, 38.91), VES = c(86, 92.4, 91.4, 84.8, 
86, 88.1, 88.9, 86.5, 90.8, 93.2, 94.7, 94.8, 92.6, 93.7, 95.9, 
93.1, 101.4, 101.1, 89.4, 97.6, 105.1, 100.3, 97.5, 100.7, 99.8, 
108, 105.6, 104.5, 108.3, 106.5), QC = c(7.8, 8.5, 8.3, 7.5, 
7.7, 8.1, 8.2, 8.2, 8.6, 9.1, 9.5, 9.5, 9.4, 10, 10.4, 10.3, 
11.3, 11.5, 10.5, 11.6, 12.7, 12.3, 12.3, 12.9, 13, 14.2, 14.2, 
14.4, 15.1, 15.2), IC = c(3.9, 4.2, 4.1, 3.7, 3.8, 4, 4.1, 4, 
4.3, 4.5, 4.7, 4.7, 4.6, 4.9, 5.1, 5.1, 5.6, 5.7, 5.2, 5.8, 6.3, 
6.1, 6.1, 6.4, 6.4, 7, 7, 7.1, 7.5, 7.5), WCI = c(4.7, 5.1, 5, 
4.5, 4.6, 4.9, 4.9, 4.9, 5.2, 5.5, 5.7, 5.7, 5.6, 6, 6.2, 6.2, 
6.8, 6.9, 6.3, 7, 7.6, 7.4, 7.4, 7.7, 7.8, 8.5, 8.5, 8.7, 9.1, 
9.1), RVSi = c(1819, 1657, 1709, 1890, 1832, 1745, 1729, 1732, 
1641, 1555, 1486, 1480, 1505, 1423, 1358, 1371, 1256, 1224, 1347, 
1216, 1112, 1151, 1152, 1096, 1092, 993, 993, 978, 930, 928), 
    RVS = c(901, 821, 846, 936, 907, 865, 857, 858, 813, 770, 
    736, 733, 745, 705, 673, 679, 622, 606, 667, 603, 551, 570, 
    571, 543, 541, 492, 492, 484, 461, 460), VTD = c(137.5, 146.4, 
    149.6, 138.6, 146.4, 137.2, 142.2, 140.7, 148.5, 146.9, 153.6, 
    152.3, 144.2, 144, 147.5, 147.3, 146.3, 155.9, 142.4, 151.3, 
    152.8, 151.4, 154.3, 158.4, 159.5, 157.2, 159.8, 155.4, 150.9, 
    152.8), FE = c(62.7, 63.1, 61.1, 61.3, 58.8, 64.2, 62.4, 
    61.5, 61.1, 63.4, 61.6, 62.3, 64.2, 65.1, 65, 63.2, 69.3, 
    64.8, 62.7, 64.5, 68.8, 66.3, 63.2, 63.6, 62.8, 68.7, 66.2, 
    67.3, 71.8, 69.7), O2Hb = c("3.8E-3", "0.37130000000000002", 
    "0.10929999999999999", "0.1457", "0.24440000000000001", "0.39960000000000001", 
    "0.51039999999999996", "0.28970000000000001", "0.1762", "0.78080000000000005", 
    "1.0116000000000001", "1.2717000000000001", "1.4643999999999999", 
    "2.5387", "2.3233000000000001", "2.5627", "2.5230000000000001", 
    "2.7890000000000001", "2.8567", "3.5232999999999999", "3.7351999999999999", 
    "4.2393000000000001", "4.3661000000000003", "4.3578000000000001", 
    "4.2431000000000001", "4.6954000000000002", "4.5110000000000001", 
    "5.1020000000000003", "4.9044999999999996", "4.8182999999999998"
    ), HHb = c(-0.292, -0.3309, -0.2811, -0.1445, -0.1007, -0.2498, 
    -0.4758, -0.2753, -0.0079, -0.2002, -0.4731, -0.3644, -0.5278, 
    -0.7466, -0.8117, -0.8199, -1.0041, -1.1128, -0.9041, -0.9066, 
    -1.0106, -0.9902, -0.9717, -0.9746, -1.0317, -1.0096, -0.9691, 
    -1.0462, -0.8992, -0.8552), tHb = c("-0.28820000000000001", 
    "4.0399999999999998E-2", "-0.17180000000000001", "1.1999999999999999E-3", 
    "0.14369999999999999", "0.14979999999999999", "3.4599999999999999E-2", 
    "1.44E-2", "0.16830000000000001", "0.58050000000000002", 
    "0.53849999999999998", "0.9073", "0.93659999999999999", "1.7921", 
    "1.5116000000000001", "1.7427999999999999", "1.5188999999999999", 
    "1.6761999999999999", "1.9525999999999999", "2.6166999999999998", 
    "2.7246000000000001", "3.2490000000000001", "3.3944000000000001", 
    "3.3832", "3.2113999999999998", "3.6859000000000002", "3.5419", 
    "4.0556999999999999", "4.0053000000000001", "3.9630999999999998"
    ), HbDiff = c("0.29580000000000001", "0.70209999999999995", 
    "0.39050000000000001", "0.29020000000000001", "0.34510000000000002", 
    "0.64939999999999998", "0.98619999999999997", "0.56499999999999995", 
    "0.18410000000000001", "0.98099999999999998", "1.4846999999999999", 
    "1.6361000000000001", "1.9922", "3.2852999999999999", "3.1349999999999998", 
    "3.3826000000000001", "3.5270999999999999", "3.9018000000000002", 
    "3.7608000000000001", "4.4298999999999999", "4.7458", "5.2294999999999998", 
    "5.3377999999999997", "5.3323999999999998", "5.2747999999999999", 
    "5.7050000000000001", "5.4802", "6.1482000000000001", "5.8037000000000001", 
    "5.6734999999999998"), id = c("AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", 
    "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", 
    "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", 
    "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", 
    "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", 
    "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", 
    "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", 
    "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1", "AC12-PRD-C1"
    ), body_mass = c("84", "84", "84", "84", "84", "84", "84", 
    "84", "84", "84", "84", "84", "84", "84", "84", "84", "84", 
    "84", "84", "84", "84", "84", "84", "84", "84", "84", "84", 
    "84", "84", "84"), training = c("linear", "linear", "linear", 
    "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", 
    "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", 
    "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", 
    "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", "linear", 
    "linear", "linear", "linear")), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

To do so, I used this code to combine my data and select the rows and columns I want:

```
load_files <- function(files){
  temp <- read_excel(files) %>% 
    select(-(c(8:11, 14:15, 18:23))) %>%
    mutate(id = pull(.[4,1])) %>% ##ID
    mutate(body_mass = pull(.[7,3])) %>% ##body mass
    mutate(training = pull(.[4,2])) %>% ##training group
    set_names(c("time", "power", "hr", "fr", "VE", "absVO2", "VCO2", "PETCO2", "VES", "QC", "IC", "WCI", "RVSi", "RVS", "VTD", "FE", "O2Hb", "HHb", "tHb", "HbDiff", "id", "body_mass", "training")) %>% 
    slice(86:which(grepl("ration", VE))-1) %>% ##until recovery period
    mutate_at(vars(1:16), as.numeric) %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(18), as.numeric) %>% 
    mutate(time = format(as.POSIXct(Sys.Date() + time), "%H:%M", tz="UTC"),
           absVO2 = absVO2/1000, 
           VCO2 = VCO2/1000)
}

df <- map_df(file_list, load_files)
```

But I get this output:

```
Error in `set_names()`:
! The size of `nm` (23) must be compatible with the size of `x` (25).
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

It was working before, but this I have added column in the Excel files, it does work anymore.

Thank you for your support!

Comment: Your `select` line excludes ranges of columns, but it seems in this case (for at least one of the excel files) there are more remaining columns than when you ran this previously, so that there are 25 columns at the `set_names` line which specifies 23 column names. You might use the `range` parameter of `read_excel` like `read_excel(path, range = cell_cols("A:W"))` to make sure no extra columns come along for the ride. (Assuming they should be excluded.)

Comment: Try `file_widths <- function(files){ temp <- read_excel(files); ncol(temp)};  map_df(file_list, file_widths)` to check if any files are being read in wider.

Comment: You were right, there was one file with 25 columns. I corrected it, now I get this message: `Warning message:
Problem while computing VCO2 = .Primitive("as.double")(VCO2).
i NAs introduced by coercion`

Comment: Your `VCO2` column is not reading in unambiguously as a number when you run `as.numeric` on it. Perhaps you had a blank, or some non-numeric text at some point in that column. You can ignore it if NA is the desired output for that situation.